# Defaults in types possible?

Tags: typescript, types, default

I'm playing with types and classes in Typescript...
Is there a way to set default values on optional attributes directly in a type definition? Or another neat way to do so?
This is part of my playfile. (creating a polygon-widget). As the style-settings are optional, I would love to have defaults there.

```
type CustomLine = {
    x1: number;
    y1: number;
    x2: number;
    y2: number;
    style?: {
        opacity?: number;
        display?: 'inherit' | 'inline' | 'none';
        fill?: string;
        strokeWidth?: number;
    };  
};
interface LineInterFace {
    length: number;
}
function length(l: CustomLine): number {
    let dx = l.x2 - l.x1;
    let dy = l.y2 - l.y1;
    return Number(Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));

}
```

Thanks in advance. Barb

(Edit...and the instantiation ;))
`let typeTestLine: CustomLine = { x1: 3, y1: 5, x2: 9, y2: 22, style: { opacity: 1, display: 'inline', fill: 'blue' } }`

Comment: No, the TypeScript type system is completely [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript; `CustomLine` is not present at all in the code that runs, so there's nowhere for a default to be written.  If you want defaults you need to write code that does this, possibly via a `class` implementation.  See the linked question/answers for more info.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks.  I'm writing this in an environment running on older JS. There I can create and inspect CustomLine (But can't manage to get defaults or to get `length` running as proper method. So I'll try on to find some outdated info...
One of the links above perfectly answers my question. (Hadn't found that before)